# Is Jackson JSON Processor secure against injection attacks such as XSS?

Tags: jackson

Is [Jackson JSON Processor](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) secure enough, by default, against injection attacks?

Comment: Injection of what?

Comment: Please explain what exactly you mean.

Comment: @gnasher729 Compared to the OWASP JSON Sanitizer (https://github.com/owasp/json-sanitizer) how secure is Jackson?